# usort() - Sorting an array in PHP

Tags: php, usort

I'm new here in.

I have a quick question:

I have an array that looks like so -

```
$array = array(413, 913, 5);

foreach($array as $arr){
 echo $arr . '<br />';
}
```

And the output is -

```
413
913
5
```

How can I use the **usort()** function to make the script output -

```
913
5
413
```

If you could help me that would be great! Thank you.

Comment: what kind of sorting is that ?

Comment: @Pogrindis I'm writing a small script to sort a couple of items from the database in a custom form.

Comment: sort them by what ? That looks completely random

Comment: So, your goal is to sort numers descending, basing on first digit?

Comment: He wants to sort by first digit @Pogrindis

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to sort reversed by digits from left to right, ie. as though they are strings

Just use a normal sort as string values:

```
$array = array(413, 913, 5);

rsort($array, SORT_STRING);
var_dump($array);
```

Comment: Deciphering skills are strong with this one

Comment: I bet you never bought the line *these are not the droids you are looking for...* in your life have you? Seeing that answer is some real jedi-master stuff right there.